# If a series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}$ converges, then $(a_{k})\to 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to go with the way Abbott was illustrating in his "Understanding Analysis." He uses the Cauchy Criterion for Series (Theorem 2.7.2) to prove this Theorem. Here is my attempt at what he was going for:

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}$ converges

$\implies[\forall\epsilon>0][\exists N\in\mathbb{N}][n>m\geq N\implies|a_{m+1}+\dots+a_{n}|<\epsilon]$.

Consider when $n=m+1$, then $|a_{m+1}-0|<\epsilon$.

Let $k=m+1$.

So,

$[\forall\epsilon>0][\exists N\in\mathbb{N}][k\geq N\implies |a_{k}-0|<\epsilon]$

$\implies (a_{k})\to 0$.

Comment: The position of the $\forall \epsilon>0$ and the $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ should be swapped.

Comment: Here the positive integer $N$ depends on the choice of $\epsilon$ .Hence you have to change the order of the quantifier $\forall$ and $\exists$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the correction! I am self studying through Abbott's book. Does everything else seem alright?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Theorem.** Let $\{a_n\}_{n\geq n_0}$ a real sequence. Necessary condition so that $\sum_{n=n_0}^{+\infty}a_n$ converges is that $a_n\to 0$ when $n\to +\infty$

**Proof.** Let $s_m=\sum_{n=n_0}^{m}a_n$ the sequence of the partial sums. We have that:
$$s_{m+1}=\sum_{n=n_0}^{m+1}a_n$$
Now, we can calculate the limit:
$$\lim_{m\to +\infty}s_{m+1}-s_m$$
*Lemma.* Let $\{c_n\}_{n\geq n_0}$. If $\lim_{n\to +\infty}c_n$ exist, then $\lim_{n\to +\infty}c_{n+1}$ and $\lim_{n\to +\infty}c_n$ are equal.

Thus:
$$\lim_{m\to +\infty}s_{m+1}-s_m=0\implies \lim_{m\to +\infty}a_{m+1}=0$$

So, $a_n\to 0$ when $n\to+\infty$.

Note that is a **necessary condition** because $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ diverges, but $\frac{1}{n}\to 0$.
Instead, $\frac{1}{n^2}\to 0$ and $\sum_{n=1}{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges.

Comment: I like that Lemma! Very intuitive.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 4):

More easily : if $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ then $a_n = S_n - S_{n-1} \to S - S = 0$ where $S =  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$

Comment: Thank you! This proof is great, but I wanted to do a proof in the style that Abbott was going for.